# question structure for p5.js conditional statements

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I keep tripping up on the below conditional statements, can anybody help me to think about structuring them correctly? I would like to understand what i am doing wrong and how i can solve myself in the future. I can solve the others but not these:

```js
//Write conditional statements to change the amount of each substance ...
 
//- When either snakeVenom dips below 0.73, alcohol dips below 0.63, arsenic dips below 0.71, or perhaps warfarin goes above 0.54, reduce antivenom by 0.03
if((snakeVenom < 0.73 || alcohol < 0.63 && arsenic < 0.71) || warfarin > 0.54 )
{
 antivenom -= 0.03
}
 
//- If deadly_nightshade dips below 0.45 or amanita_mushrooms goes above 0.33, whilst at the same time, lead goes above 0.52 or formaldehyde dips below 0.31, try increasing antivenom by 0.04
if(deadly_nightshade < 0.45 || amanita_mushrooms < 0.33 && (lead > 0.52 || formaldehyde < 0.31))
{
   antivenom += 0.04
}
```

Comment: The first statement is `snakeVenom < 0.73 || alcohol < 0.63 || arsenic < 0.71 || warfarin > 0.54` However, on the second one, are you asking if `lead ` and `formaldehyde ` happen "whilst at the same time" while `deadly_nightshade` and `amanita_mushrooms` happen independently?

Comment: Could you add the conditionals (in plain text) in your question (and not in code)?

Comment: I believe the second one is saying that either deadly nightshade or amanita_mushrooms and at the same either lead or... Hope that makes sense

Comment: @AshutoshKS the plain English is already  there in the comments

Comment: @Pointy Yes, but the first conditional sentence was little confusing, so I asked. :)

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this comment:

> When either snakeVenom dips below 0.73, alcohol dips below 0.63, arsenic dips below 0.71, or perhaps warfarin goes above 0.54, reduce antivenom by 0.03

as meaning that any of the independent conditions

- snakeVenom < 0.73
- alcohol < 0.63
- arsenic < 0.71
- warfarin > 0.54

indicate the need to reduce antivenom.  Thus the `&&` in the middle of your conditional expression is wrong; it should all be `||`.  Note that it's not 100% clear that I'm right because English is not as unambiguous as a programming language, but if I am right then your first `if` statement should be

```
if(snakeVenom < 0.73 || alcohol < 0.63 || arsenic < 0.71 || warfarin > 0.54 )
```

Similarly,

> If deadly_nightshade dips below 0.45 or amanita_mushrooms goes above 0.33, whilst at the same time, lead goes above 0.52 or formaldehyde dips below 0.31, try increasing antivenom by 0.04

means that both of these conditions being true:

- deadly_nightshade < 0.45 or amanita_mushrooms > 0.33
- lead > 0.52 or formaldehyde < 0.31

means that antivenom should be increased. Therefore the second `if` needs extra parentheses for the first `||` expression:

```
if ((deadly_nightshade < 0.45 || amanita_mushrooms < 0.33) && (lead > 0.52 || formaldehyde < 0.31))
```

because `||` binds less tightly than `&&`; it's like the relationship between `+` and `*` in arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks i have the same thought process as you and english is my native language but i keep getting this wrong and am now in danger of getting locked out and having to attempt a new puzzle.

Comment: Well give it a try, I may be wrong because I am not familiar with the wording of the actual original "puzzle" you're working on